# packer hcl2 how to use locals in -var-file or alternative pattern

Tags: packer, hcl

in my original json for packer it was easy to assemble variables which reference other variables.
Now that packer recommends to use hcl2 i am wondering how to use this pattern (or antipattern in hcl2) .

The basic run was

```
packer build -var-file ubuntu.json template.json
packer build -var-file fedora.json template.json
```

with -var-file containing a different "boot_command" variable which was assembled from with internal variables.  *example has pseudo code, just to show the problem and to avoid to show a long line*

```
{
  "boot_command": "ubuntu <esc><esc><wait>< preseed/url=http://{{ .HTTPIP }}:{{ .HTTPPort }}"
}

{
  "boot_command": "fedora <esc><esc><wait>< url=http://{{ .HTTPIP }}:{{ .HTTPPort }}"
}
```

I have converted all of this to to hcl.

```
packer build -var-file fedora.pkr.hcl template.pkr.hcl
packer build -var-file fedora.pkr.hcl template.pkr.hcl
```

When it try to this in hcl it doesn't allow me to assign strings, which contain variables. The error message is somewhat cryptic "**blocks are not allowed here".**

```
locals {
  boot_command = [ "ubuntu <esc><esc><wait>< preseed/url=http://{{ .HTTPIP }}:{{ .HTTPPort }}"]
}
```

I am wondering how this is done in hcl2 correctly, because when I put the locals section into the template.pkr.hcl as follows, it works, but now i am wondering how i could switch from "ubuntu" to "fedora" as there is no "if ubuntu" then this boot_command content and then another "boot_command"content, as the sequence  of keys is of course different with fedora

How would i do this correctly in hcl2, or is the consequence that i need to maintain two copies of the template.pkr.hcl  only to have different boot_commands?

Comment: Valid question, have you found a solution to this yet?

Comment: No - reduced the usage of packer, as I consider this a proprietary technology.